# Dotnet program using Crystalreport 13.0.18 version freezes

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have an application hosted on windows server which takes the XML as an input for printing and sets the printername which is received in the XML file. From couple of weeks, the program is not able to spool any requests to the network printer and after analysing the logs, at the below line the program freezes:

**ReportDocument.PrintOptions.NoPrinter = false**

Also in few scenarios we have seen that the spooling sometimes stops in the middle of the request. Application is been running with a service account.

Would appreciate if anyone can suggest or advice what can be done in such situations?

Comment: Have you used a Try Catch block to try and isolate and capture the error message?  You should also review the Event Viewer in windows for any errors that may help identify the problem.

Comment: Code doesnt proceeds after that statement and in the event log, found two things: Eventid 823 which states changing the default printer and splwow64 exe in the task manager waiting threads.